Object conversion from one format to another
I am novice to javascript and node.js. I was able to create the following object from a json file after filtering, sorting and grouping.
{
    "2016": {
        "Delhi Daredevils": 8,
        "Gujarat Lions": 8,
        "Kings XI Punjab": 4,
        "Kolkata Knight Riders": 6,
        "Mumbai Indians": 7,
        "Rising Pune Supergiants": 4,
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore": 5,
        "Sunrisers Hyderabad": 7
    },
    "2017": {
        "Delhi Daredevils": 5,
        "Gujarat Lions": 6,
        "Kings XI Punjab": 4,
        "Kolkata Knight Riders": 9,
        "Mumbai Indians": 9,
        "Rising Pune Supergiant": 6,
        "Royal Challengers Bangalore": 5,
        "Sunrisers Hyderabad": 4
    }
}

Code used for generating this output is given below.
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const fs = require("fs");
const results = [];
let groupedResults = [];

// generic comparison function
cmp = function (x, y) {
  return x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0;
};

//Define function with three arguments array, p1 and p2
function dataCount(array, p1, p2) {
  const group = {};

  // initialize a for loop
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //adding properties of array with _
    const batch = array[i][p1];
    const batch1 = array[i][p2];

    if (!group[batch]) {
      group[batch] = {};
      if (!group[batch][batch1]) {
        group[batch][batch1] = 1;
      } else {
        group[batch][batch1]++;
      }
    } else {
      if (!group[batch][batch1]) {
        group[batch][batch1] = 1;
      } else {
        group[batch][batch1]++;
      }
    }
  }
  //return group value
  return group;
}

fs.createReadStream("matches.csv")
  .pipe(csv())
  .on("data", (data) => {
    if (
      (data.SEASON === "2016" || data.SEASON === "2017") &&
      data.TOSS_DECISION === "field"
    ) {
      results.push(data);
    }
  })
  .on("data", () => {
    results.sort((a, b) => {
      return cmp(
        [cmp(a.TOSS_WINNER, b.TOSS_WINNER), cmp(a.SEASON, b.SEASON)],
        [cmp(b.TOSS_WINNER, a.TOSS_WINNER), cmp(b.SEASON, a.SEASON)],
      );
    });
  })
  .on("data", () => {
    groupedResults = dataCount(results, "SEASON", "TOSS_WINNER");
  })
  .on("data", () => {})
  .on("end", () => {
    fs.writeFileSync("output.txt", JSON.stringify(groupedResults), () => {
      console.log("Output successful");
    });
  });


Now I want to covert this object to the following format:
{
    "2016": {
        "0": [
            "Delhi Daredevils",
            8
        ],
        "1": [
            "Gujarat Lions",
            8
        ],
        "2": [
            "Kings XI Punjab",
            4
        ],
        "3": [
            "Kolkata Knight Riders",
            6
        ],
        "4": [
            "Mumbai Indians",
            7
        ],
        "5": [
            "Rising Pune Supergiants",
            4
        ],
        "6": [
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
            5
        ],
        "7": [
            "Sunrisers Hyderabad",
            7
        ]
    },
    "2017": {
        "0": [
            "Delhi Daredevils",
            5
        ],
        "1": [
            "Gujarat Lions",
            6
        ],
        "2": [
            "Kings XI Punjab",
            4
        ],
        "3": [
            "Kolkata Knight Riders",
            9
        ],
        "4": [
            "Mumbai Indians",
            9
        ],
        "5": [
            "Rising Pune Supergiant",
            6
        ],
        "6": [
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
            5
        ],
        "7": [
            "Sunrisers Hyderabad",
            4
        ]
    }
}

How can this be accomplished? We must use callback as this is a node.js code and will run asynchronously.

It seems you could map over the team name keys (Object.keys(data["2016"]) and push each item into an array.

Please don't use the JSON tag for JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals.

Unrelated to your problem: Your code is unnecessarily inefficient. You're sorting the data and generating the result for each row of input data. You should read the results array, sort it once, group it once and write the output. "I was able to create the following object from a json file" matches.csv looks like a CSV file, not like a JSON file.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

You can loop over the object keys.
I saved your data to data.json:
{
  "2016": {
    "Delhi Daredevils": 8,
    "Gujarat Lions": 8,
    "Kings XI Punjab": 4,
    "Kolkata Knight Riders": 6,
    "Mumbai Indians": 7,
    "Rising Pune Supergiants": 4,
    "Royal Challengers Bangalore": 5,
    "Sunrisers Hyderabad": 7
  },
  "2017": {
    "Delhi Daredevils": 5,
    "Gujarat Lions": 6,
    "Kings XI Punjab": 4,
    "Kolkata Knight Riders": 9,
    "Mumbai Indians": 9,
    "Rising Pune Supergiant": 6,
    "Royal Challengers Bangalore": 5,
    "Sunrisers Hyderabad": 4
  }
}

Then I created a .js file:
const data = require("./data.json");

const transformData = (data) => {
  const transformedData = {};

  //loop over the keys
  Object.keys(data).forEach((year) => {
    transformedData[year] = {};
    const teams = Object.entries(data[year]);

    teams.forEach((team, index) => {
      transformedData[year][index] = team;
    });
  });

  return transformedData;
};

const transformedData = transformData(data);

console.log(transformedData);

Here, if you want to use a for loop
const data = require("./data.json");

const transformData = (data) => {
  const transformedData = {};

  //store the keys in a variable
  const years = Object.keys(data);

  //loop over the variable
  for (let i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    const year = years[i];
    transformedData[year] = {};

    const teams = Object.entries(data[year]);

    for (let j = 0; j < teams.length; j++) {
      const team = teams[j];
      transformedData[year][j] = team;
    }
  }

  return transformedData;
};

const transformedData = transformData(data);
console.log(transformedData);

Output:
{
  '2016': {
    '0': [ 'Delhi Daredevils', 8 ],
    '1': [ 'Gujarat Lions', 8 ],
    '2': [ 'Kings XI Punjab', 4 ],
    '3': [ 'Kolkata Knight Riders', 6 ],
    '4': [ 'Mumbai Indians', 7 ],
    '5': [ 'Rising Pune Supergiants', 4 ],
    '6': [ 'Royal Challengers Bangalore', 5 ],
    '7': [ 'Sunrisers Hyderabad', 7 ]
  },
  '2017': {
    '0': [ 'Delhi Daredevils', 5 ],
    '1': [ 'Gujarat Lions', 6 ],
    '2': [ 'Kings XI Punjab', 4 ],
    '3': [ 'Kolkata Knight Riders', 9 ],
    '4': [ 'Mumbai Indians', 9 ],
    '5': [ 'Rising Pune Supergiant', 6 ],
    '6': [ 'Royal Challengers Bangalore', 5 ],
    '7': [ 'Sunrisers Hyderabad', 4 ]
  }
}

Hope this helps.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? Please don't post a runnable code snippet if it can't be run.

@jabaa ok then I'll copy paste it

Please edit and then click the [<>] and give a [mcve] so we can check it work with just a click

You can reformat your data by reducing the object.keys and then convert the deeper to an object by spreading the result of Object.entries


const data = {
    "2016": {"Delhi Daredevils": 8, "Gujarat Lions": 8, "Kings XI Punjab": 4, "Kolkata Knight Riders": 6, "Mumbai Indians": 7, "Rising Pune Supergiants": 4, "Royal Challengers Bangalore": 5, "Sunrisers Hyderabad": 7 },
    "2017": {"Delhi Daredevils": 5, "Gujarat Lions": 6, "Kings XI Punjab": 4, "Kolkata Knight Riders": 9, "Mumbai Indians": 9, "Rising Pune Supergiant": 6, "Royal Challengers Bangalore": 5, "Sunrisers Hyderabad": 4 }
};

const res = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, year) => {
    acc[year] = { ...Object.entries(data[year]) }
    return acc;
}, {});
  
console.log(res);



